# Does rtabmap deal with moving objects?

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was reading this guide:
http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping

I am unsure whether rtabmap supports moving objects (for example, after generating a map, if a chair moves, or if the mapping captured a person who is moving, do these things throw off rtabmap's localization)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236052/does-rtabmap-deal-with-moving-objects?/) by [bzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26225/bzhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

If the moved object has a lot of discriminative visual features and it takes a big part of the field of view, it may cause a wrong global localization when seen again in a different location. Example in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8v70DZxLF8. The same problem can happen between locations looking very similar. As shown in the video, it is possible to detect such loop closure detection / localization failures with approaches keeping the map's graph consistent.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0